# When I use date_add in where is not working, why?

Tags: mysql, sql, dateadd

```
SELECT * 
FROM PATIENT
WHERE PATIENTNUM = (SELECT PATIENTNUM
                     FROM CONSULTATION
                     WHERE CONSULTATIONDATE =  
                     (SELECT DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS DAYTOM);
```

This is not working.

But when I insert only this

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS DAYTOM
```

its working...

Why??

Comment: it is not working means what? what exactly not working?

Comment: what is error show up

Comment: # 1064 - Syntax error in Line 6

Comment: WHERE CONSULTATIONDATE =  (SELECT DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS DAYTOM); -# 1064 - Syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct way is

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM PATIENT
   WHERE PATIENTNUM IN (SELECT PATIENTNUM
                 FROM CONSULTATION
                 WHERE CONSULTATIONDATE IN  (SELECT DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)             AS   DAYTOM));
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed one bracket?

```
SELECT * 
FROM PATIENT
WHERE PATIENTNUM = (SELECT PATIENTNUM
                     FROM CONSULTATION
                     WHERE CONSULTATIONDATE =  (SELECT DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS DAYTOM));
```